# Facebook ads account Total Spent - UI not matching API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm getting a browser-API discrepancy that I cannot fathom out. In the browser, when I go to

https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/home/?account_id=1376129679277116&time_start=2013-07-17&time_end=2013-07-31&level=campaign&status=100&sort_key=405&sort_dir=desc

and sum the "Total Spent", I get $2,882.38. However when I do the equivalent request through the graph explorer

[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=act_1376129679277116%2Fstats%2F1372651200%2F1375243200%3Faccess_token%TOKEN&version=v2.1](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=act_1376129679277116%2Fstats%2F1372651200%2F1375243200%3Faccess_token%25TOKEN&version=v2.1)

the Total Spent is $2,790.21 - a difference of $92.17.

When I make the same request through the API, I get $2,790.21 which agrees with the graph explorer.

Anyone know where this $92.17 difference might be creeping in?  Any pointers gladly received.

Thanks, Peter

Comment: File a bug in https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: FTR FB acknowledge it's a valid bug and are looking into it.

Comment: can you link to the bug?

Comment: @PaulBain - here you go https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1583238165237001/